# LT1054 Consume more current

Tags: switching-regulator

why is the LT1054 Consume more current nearly 160ma ,for actual 40ma load? .so battery voltage drop significantly . can i get an proper solution?. following is the circuit ,i have used with 10uf tantalum capacitor.[image]

Comment: What input and output voltage do you have? What load for this voltages (resistance)?

Comment: I would also want to know where your 40mA number came from. That pasted circuit also tells us nothing about how you have it actually hooked up. For all we know your circuit could be set up wrong.

Comment: input = 9v battery.output= +/- 17v .i am using +ve supply to regulator 7805 and then to microcontroller and lcds .it consumes nearly 40ma current. as aresult battery voltage drop suddenly and reaches minimum 3v within 10 minutes. it off the overall system..but, after 5 minutes,i can again start the system with 8.5v for same battery and again it works for nearly 10 minutes.can you suggest a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's outputting a total of 4 times the input voltage (minus some diode drops and the internal loss).

By conservation of energy you should expect it to be drawing about 4 times the output current from the input supply.

Comment: input = 9v battery.output= +/- 17v .i am using +ve supply to regulator 7805 and then to microcontroller and lcds .it consumes nearly 40ma current. as aresult battery voltage drop suddenly and reaches minimum 3v within 10 minutes. it off the overall system..but, after 5 minutes,i can again start the system with 8.5v for same battery and again it works for nearly 10 minutes.can you suggest a solution

Comment: If you need 5V at substantial current do not get it from a doubled 9V and linear regulator, rather directly from the 9V via an efficient switching regulator with inductor.

Comment: sir, i need +5v and -5v from a single 9v supply.can you suggest a better method?

Comment: Assuming -5V draw is small, generate +5 with the switching regulator and -5 from the +5 with a charge pump IC such as 7660 or more modern variants. The power efficiency should be quite good.

Comment: can you explain?,pls

Comment: can i use 7805 with 9v battery for +5v?

Comment: i have used 9v battery directly to 7805 for grnerating +5v.inverter circuitry was made up with lt1054 for -5v by same battery and consume less current 35ma instead of 160ma .so i am happy now.the only problem,remaining is that voltage drop of battery for continuous use,nearly 20 minutes.can you suggest a solution?

Comment: Using a switching regulator could reduce that somewhat- maybe by 30%, but at some point you have to either reduce the current draw from the circuit or use a better (eg. alkaline) battery or use 6 AA batteries.